# How can I rotate Am chart in v4?

Tags: amcharts

> How can I rotate Am chart in v4?

I want rotate am chart axis like x axes data to y1 and y1 axes to top of chart like:

https://c3js.org/samples/axes_rotated.html

Comment: What you have there so far? Show us your code.

Answer (score 5):

Rotating v4's charts is simply a matter of assigning the category/value axis to the desired xAxes/yAxes array and setting the `oppsite` and `inversed` property to true in the axes' `renderer` objects, depending on the axis. For example:

```
// place category axis on the y axis 
// use inversed to reverse the order so 
// the first category is on top
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
// ...
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;

// place value axis on the x axis and use the opposite property to move it up top
var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
// ...
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;
```

Demo:

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 3025
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441
}];

// place category axis on the y axis 
// use inversed to reverse the order so 
// the first category is on top
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;

// place value axis on the x axis and use the opposite property to move it up top
var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueX = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryY = "country";
series.tooltipText = "[{categoryX}: bold]{valueY}[/]";
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 95%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks , I did same